# how to return a true or false from an asynchronous callback to break the some() loop?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mongoose

```
user.some(function(value) {

    CreateRoomHash(userID, value._id, function (err, roomhash) {
        if(err) console.log(err);
        if(roomhash) {
        console.log("ROOMHASH:" + roomhash);
            retrieveRoom(roomhash, function(err, room) {
                if(err) console.log(err);
                if(room) {
                    console.log("ROOM FOUND: " + room);
                    if(room.status) {
                        console.log("Existing room found:"+ roomsha);
                        JoinRoom(roomsha);
                        response.json({Roomhash: roomsha});
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        console.log("ROOM STATUS IS FALSE");
                        return false;
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("ROOM NOT FOUND");
                    var newRoom = CreateRoom(roomsha, userID, matchedID); 
                    console.log("No existing room found, new room created:" + roomsha);
                    response.json({Roomhash: newRoom});
                    return true;
                }
            });
            console.log("COOL:"+cool)
            }
            console.log("COOL:"+cool)
        });
    });
});
```

Beginner here. I have two nested callback functions, CreateRoomHash and retrive Room. How do return true or false for either of my callback functions so I can break out of my some()?

Comment: look into [async.some](https://github.com/caolan/async#somearr-iterator-callback)

Comment: i updated the problem, if you want to take a look. I'm using async.some but it's doing the same thing.

Comment: Look at using [`async.some`](https://github.com/caolan/async#some) instead, for the reasons described in the linked duplicate.